# Как правильно сделать запрос к api yandex

Tags: python, api, requests, get, переменные

Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно оформить запрос к api yandex и получить ответ в формате Json, но чтобы не каждый раз вводить вручную начальный параметр since_datetime,а например приравнять данный параметр к переменной = datetime.now().isoformat ()
Мой запрос:

```
import requests
import json


url = 'https://b2b-api.go.yandex.ru/integration/2.0/orders/tanker?since_datetime=2022-05-12T13:32:49.123&since_datetime=2022-05-15T06:11:52.834’
headers = {'Authorization': Bearer токен'}
response = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers)
print(response.json())
```

Comment: Тогда, f-строки вам в помощь.

Comment: Если можно приложите пример кода

Comment: Нет, читайте.ㅤㅤ

Comment: Спасибо код сработал)

Comment: Не за что. Если что, вы можете написать строку прямо вот так: `f"https://b2b-api.go.yandex.ru/integration/2.0/orders/tanker?since_datetime={now_date}&since_datetime={end_date}"`

Comment: Могли бы Вы помочь мне еще с одним вопросом по данной теме просто направить в правильное русло?

Comment: Если у вас возникли какие-то проблемы при написании кода, то тогда [задайте новый вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Убедитесь, что ваш вопрос будет следовать [стандартам для вопросов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Хорошо спасибо)

Answer (score 1):

```
import requests
import json
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer token'}
now_date = datetime.now().isoformat()
end_date = "2024-12-31T00:00:00.000"



def get_info():
    s = requests.Session()
    response = s.get('https://b2b-api.go.yandex.ru/integration/2.0/orders/tanker?' + f"since_datetime={now_date}&since_datetime={end_date}", headers=headers)
    data = response.json()
    print(data)
```